# Kivy: Update to ListView data with ListAdapter or DictAdapter does not change button text

Tags: python, listview, kivy, listadapter

In a container widget I have a `ListView` with adapter:

```
list_item_args_converter = \
        lambda row_index, selectable: \
        {'text': "[{}] {}: {}".format(row_index, selectable['t'], selectable['v']),
        'size_hint_y': None, 'height': 25}

my_list_adapter = \
    ListAdapter(data=my_data,
                args_converter=list_item_args_converter,
                selection_mode='single',
                allow_empty_selection=False,
                cls=ListItemButton)

self.list_view = ListView(adapter=my_list_adapter)
self.add_widget(self.list_view)
```

and `my_data = [{'t':str(i), 'v':random.randint(1,10)} for i in range(5)]`.
Naively I assume `mv.list_view.adapter.data[0]['v'] = '42'` (where `mv` is the container widget) dispatches a change event on the list, thus changing the first list view button's text to '`[0] 0: 42`'.

Yet nothing happens.

Likewise, if the adapter is a `DictAdapter` and it is changed similarly (i.e. if values of the `dict` are `dict`s themselves, changing these `dict`s), nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change event is only triggered if items are `append`ed, `insert`ed, `remove`d, `pop`ed, `slice`d, `sort`ed, etc., but not if the  items' identities remain unchanged. In a case like the question's, one has to manually dispatch the change event. If `adapter` is a `ListAdapter`, this can be done so:

```
adapter.data.prop.dispatch(adapter.data.obj())
```

In case of a `DictAdapter`, the following is appropriate:

```
adapter.data.prop.dispatch(adapter.data.obj)
```

(this just cost me a day of my life. Hope someone else finds this useful …)

Comment: Hee, thanks for this answer, hope it saves me a day! I have one silly question left... where do I execute this adapter.data.prop.dispatch comand?

Comment: This seems to be pretty slow, does anybody know of a way just to update a single object which has been changed?

Comment: @zwep: Wherever (respectively whenever) your code changes the data. I put it in the on_press method of the ListItemButton.